# Mysterious: Elif and Counter Increment Bug

Tags: bash, debugging, conditional-statements

Hi I am trying to run a for loop with an increment counter that switches into an elif statement.  The for loop is a way of building a string of syllables to synthesize with macintalk.  I would like to add a short silence every 20ms but I cant seem to get it to work, I've tried a bunch of debugging steps but none seem to work.  Can anyone spot the bug that prevents the elif from being accessed?

---

EDIT

Ok so I followed the suggestion below and used -eq instead = but I noticed that the counter only resets once and does not access the conditional statement a second time.  The revised code is posted below:

```
counter=0;
for k in $indx
do
    counter=$(($counter + 1));
    echo 'increment counter'
    echo $counter
    if [ $k -eq 0 ]
    then
        stream=$stream'@_'${syllarray[k]}
    elif [ $counter -eq 20 ]
    then
        echo Adding Silence after syllable: ${syllarray[k]}
        stream=$stream'_'${syllarray[k]}'[[ slnc 20 ]]'
        counter=0;
        echo 'reset counter'
        echo $counter
    else
        stream=$stream'_'${syllarray[k]}
    fi
done
```

---

**Sample output:**

Synthesize A Syllable Stream with Predetermined Lexicon, Word Order and Phonology

Parameters:

Voice --  Victoria

Rate (words/min) --  120

Pitch Modulation Interval --  0

Baseline pitch --  55

Directory Exists :)

Opening Syllable Transcription for Victoria

0

bIY

1

bUW

2

dAE

3

dOW

4

gOW

5

kUW

6

lAE

7

pAE

8

pIY

9

rOW

10

tIY

11

tUW

Counter Balanced Stimulus Order (Indexed by Syllables in Alphabetical Order)

11 2 9 8 4 6 0 5 10 11 2 9 8 4 6 1 3 7 8 4 6 0 5 10 11 2 9 1 3 7 0 5 10 8 4 6 1 3 7 0 5 10 8 4 6 11 2 9 0 5 10 1 3 7 8 4 6 11 2 9 1 3 7 11 2 9 0 5 10 1 3 7 8 4 6 0 5 10 11 2 9 8 4 6 1 3 7 0 5 10 8 4 6 11 2 9 0 5 10 8 4 6 11 2 9 0 5 10 1 3 7 8 4 6 1 3 7 0 5 10 11 2 9 1 3 7 8 4 6 0 5 10 1 3 7 11 2 9 1 3 7 11 2 9 1 3 7 0 5 10 8 4 6 1 3 7 0 5 10 11 2 9 0 5 10 11 2 9 8 4 6 11 2 9 1 3 7 8 4 6 0 5 10 1 3 7 11 2 9 8 4 6 0 5 10 8 4 6 1 3 7 11 2 9 0 5 10 1 3 7 8 4 6 11 2 9 8 4 6 1 3 7 11 2 9 0 5 10 8 4 6 11 2 9 0 5 10 8 4 6 11 2 9 1 3 7 0 5 10 1 3 7 8 4 6 0 5 10 1 3 7 0 5 10 11 2 9 1 3 7 11 2 9 8 4 6 0 5 10 11 2 9 8 4 6 1 3 7

Creating counterbalanced stimulus stream string with proper Macintalk formatting

increment counter
1
increment counter
2
increment counter
3
increment counter
4
increment counter
5
increment counter
6
increment counter
7
increment counter
8
increment counter
9
increment counter
10
increment counter
11
increment counter
12
increment counter
13
increment counter
14
increment counter
15
increment counter
16
increment counter
17
increment counter
18
increment counter
19
increment counter
20
Adding Silence after syllable: gOW
reset counter
0
increment counter
1
..
*[truncated for clarity]*
..
increment counter
268

Printing Stream to Screen

_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW[[ slnc 20 ]]_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE

Saving Synthesized Stream

Writing to:   ./synthesis/stream-Victoria/stream.flac

Comment: `[ $k=0 ]` should be `[[ $k -eq 0 ]]`

Comment: the $k=0 works just as well as the  $k -eq 0 ; i've tried both statements and while the k conditional is accessed, the elif is not :(

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) detects common errors including this one.

Comment: can someone explain the difference between = and -eq?  is one a logical and the other an assignment?

Comment: Opposite of what one might expect, `=` does a string comparison, but `-eq` does a numeric comparison.

Comment: What is $indx? It looks to me like you only have one item to iterate over in the for loop, so naturally you don't get into the elif branch.

Comment: I print out $indx while the script runs, $indx is equal to the number array seen above in the sample output below "Creating counterbalanced stimulus stream string with proper Macintalk formatting."  I'm pretty sure that the loop goes over more than one iteration since it produces the stimulus stream.  However it only accesses the elif *ONCE* (see above sample output)